# Pages in CRM don't render

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, internet-explorer-10

I've seen this behavior a couple of times the last few days. When I try to access an organization, I get the contents of the ASPX file but they show in plain text, instead of being rendered. Anybody can confirm that behavior? Extra plus if they also can explain it.

I'm running IE10 and the behavior occurs (seldomly) on UR8. I suspect **that** is the issue but I can't explain why it happens only seldom nor why.

[image]

Comment: Not sure but perhaps ie10 has problems with crm..did you try running it using ie9?

Comment: I haven't experienced such behavior on other system than Win8/IE10 and only that particular organization. **However**, it occurs very seldom so it's uncertain if that's a coincidence. It could be the IIS or, which I suspect, **my** browser. At dynamics on-line login page, I get weird script errors. When I log in (on-premise and on-line), I frequently get JS errors **and** in the console I can see a number of complaints even when accessing a new, vanilla organization. The whole experience feels very unstable to me, on occasion.

Comment: If you hit F12 and open developer tools and change the browser mode to explicitly use 10, does it make a difference?

Comment: As far I recall, yes. However, the problem seems to stop appearing the last weeks. If it's because someone ran an update on the server, or if it's MS that updated IE or just a ghost taking vacation, we'll probably never know. Why do you ask? Do you have any ideas?